# unable to run alter database commands

Tags: sql, sql-server, recovery

One of my database has gone into the "recovery pending" mode. now I am unable to run any alter statements on this database as it always gives me the following error:

> ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database

I have checked and confirmed that there are no active connections on this database. There are also no locked processes on this database.

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: You could try taking the DB offline and then bringing it back (or 4 steps... offline, detach, attach, online).  That will sometimes fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`recovery pending` state for a database means that your server can't find needed amount of memory to maintain all the databases it have, and, to be able to work with some of the databases, it move to the `recovery` other ones (usually not so used).

You have two ways to resolve this issue: add physical resources to your server (RAM or something) or remove some unused databases from your server.

Comment: thank you for the response. There is enough  memory / resource on the server. so I reckon the problem is something else

Comment: DEfinetely not if server need to detach databases. May be there are too many of them on your server.